# How to configure Nginx with PM2 and Nuxt on an Ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, nuxt.js, pm2

#### Nuxt

I'm using a Nuxt website configured on hos `mynuxt.dev` on port 3001.
`nuxt.config.js`

```
export default {
  server: {
    host: process.env.HOST,
    port: process.env.PORT,
  },
...
}
```

When I do `npm run dev`, I see that's it's properly using these host and address.

#### /etc/hosts

I've also add this to `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 mynuxt.dev
```

#### PM2

Then, I've used `pm2` as follow:

```
npm run build
pm2 start
pm2 save
```

I can see the website running with `pm2 monit` (logs are empty, no error).

#### Nginx

Then, I configured Nginx as explained [here](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/tutorials/pm2-nginx-production-setup) (I disabled the SSL configuration):

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/mynuxt.conf`:

```
upstream my_nodejs_upstream {
    server 127.0.0.1:3001;
    keepalive 64;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    #listen 443 ssl;
    
    server_name mynuxt.dev;
    #ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/main.key;
    #ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/main.crt;
   
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        
        proxy_pass http://my_nodejs_upstream/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_read_timeout 240s;
    }
}
```

Everything seems fine with running Nginx but I don't see any log in `/var/log/nginx/access.log` and `/var/log/nginx/error.log`.

```
$ sudo  nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
$ sudo service nginx restart
$ sudo service nginx status
...active (running)...
$ sudo service php7.4-fpm status
...active (running)...
```

#### Accessing the website

Why when accessing the website from a browser at `mynuxt.dev`, I get `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` ? What's wrong in my configuration ?

How can I debug this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can help you, I don't use the "etc/hosts" config and I keep listening on "localhost:3000", as you can see in my config below (nuxt/pm2/ubuntu). It works fine.

**Nuxt**

run on `http://localhost:3000/` (as default in `nuxt.congig.js`)

**etc/hosts**

(I don't use it)

**pm2**

(similar to your commands)

**Nginx**

```
    ...

    location / {
        # without upstream on mine, but it's similar to yours
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `mynuxt.dev` to `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1 mynuxt.dev
```

then restart pm2 over again it's gonna work.

Answer (score 0):

**if you have a .output file**

your_project_name

1. backend
2. frontend

> .output
> ecosystem.config.js

> package.json

**NGINX**

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/your_app_name
server{
root /var/www/project_name/frontend/;
index index.html index.htm;
server_name your_server_name;
     location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

**switch to sites-enabled**

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/your_app_name
sudo service nginx restart
sudo service nginx status
```

*status should be active*

**and ecosystem.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
apps: [
    {
        name: 'yor_app_name', // example "MYAPP"
        port: '3000',
        exec_mode: 'cluster',
        instances: 'max',
        script: './.output/server/index.mjs',
    }
  ]
```

}

*and package.json*

```
{
   "name": "frontend",
   "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
   "main": "ecosystem.config.js",
  "scripts": {
   "start": "node .output/server/index.mjs"
  },
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC"
```

}

**finish**

```
pm2 start ecosystem.config.js
pm2 restart MYAPP
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Atyns.png)
and you should have it working. enjoy coding!!!